# How to avoid conflict between "dom" and "webworker" libs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, background-sync, typescript-lib-dom

I am using TypeScript with React, and one of the things I want to achieve is background sync for offline support.

To enable typings for service worker, I have to include the WebWorker lib, but it conflicts with DOM lib and produces an error:

```
(25,1): Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: 
EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, BlobPart, HeadersInit, BodyInit,
RequestInfo, DOMHighResTimeStamp, PerformanceEntryList, PushMessageDataInit,
VibratePattern, BufferSource, DOMTimeStamp, FormDataEntryValue, 
IDBValidKey, MessageEventSource, BinaryType, ClientTypes, 
IDBCursorDirection, IDBRequestReadyState, IDBTransactionMode, 
NotificationDirection, NotificationPermission, PushEncryptionKeyName, 
PushPermissionState, ReferrerPolicy, RequestCache, RequestCredentials, 
RequestDestination, RequestMode, RequestRedirect, ResponseType, 
ServiceWorkerState, ServiceWorkerUpdateViaCache, VisibilityState, 
WorkerType, XMLHttpRequestResponseType
```

So I am wondering if there is any workaround except for typing most of my arguments `any`.

Answer (score 1):

You can split your project into multiple parts with separate `tsconfig.json` files: one part that includes the `dom` lib and one part that includes the `webworker` lib.  You can make another part for common code that doesn't depend on either library.  You can use [project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) to help automate the build.  If this doesn't fully solve the problem, please update the question to describe the outstanding issues.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Matt, I read through the documents and tried to implement your suggestion. I had some problems, but felt like the problem belongs its own individual post, https://stackoverflow.com/q/52437384/6683308 (I am pretty new to asking questions on the internet, please let me know if I should somehow combine this two posts) but thank you for your input